# Lookup column restriction

Tags: lookup-column, column

For a school project we are setting up a SharePoint for a non profit organisation who handle clients. we have made a document library where we store documents sets for every client thats added.

In a list we use for keeping track of the time spent on each client, we use a lookup to the document library to link the time spent to a client. The problem is: the lookup not only displays the client's document sets (`=name of the client eg. "client 1"`) but also the names of documents in the document set. (eg. "client 1 - report 1"). This means when selecting a client to link the time spent to them, sharepoint's dropdown box displays all the clients names (doc sets) and the names of the documents inside.

Is there any way I could adjust the lookup so it only displays the names of the document sets without the name of documents inside it?

Answer (score 0):

In SP2010 and SP2013, certain types of fields can also be associated with a lookup column. However some fields which lookup to other lists can't be associated to the lookup

You can create a column in the document library with just the Client Name (this could be a calculated text value or a free text field).

You can then use this as the field as the look-up in the second Client work list

Comment: I already tried it with a calculated column but that didn't work, it still displayed the documents inside. only with a free text field it works, much thanks!!

Comment: In calculated columns, you can use Excel text string formulas like Left()  ... you possibly can split your client name - doc set name string this way